# Parsing multiple command line arguments in c

Tags: c, parsing, arguments, program-entry-point, argv

I have a test.c program which reads different arguments from the standard input and which should output different stuff depending on the given argument.

For example: ./test.c -a 1 -b 2 -c 3

So I wish I could go and take a certain function according to the letter, and then display something specific according to the number. So a letter is always followed by a number.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printfile();
    while ((++argv)[0]) {
        if (argv[0][0] == '-') {
            switch (argv[0][1]) {
                case 'a':
                    printf("case a\n"); test1(); break;
                case 'b':
                    printf("case b\n"); test2()); break;    
                case 'c':
                    printf("case c\n"); break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

Here my code only takes each hyphen followed by a letter. Is it possible to separate them and then put each letter with its number?

Comment: PSA: Tools like [getopt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) exist.

Comment: You have an extra `)` after `test2()`

Comment: don't call your program `test` as there's a system utility also called `test`.  It will make you make mistakes that are not your progam related and very difficult to realize.  I've seen you use a path when callint `./test` but you don't say if you are aware of the problems that can arise from calling your program like a system tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this is with the `getopt()` library.

But if you want to do it explicitly in your code, you can increment `argv` within the cases and process the next argument as a parameter.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printfile();
    while ((++argv)[0]) {
        if (argv[0][0] == '-') {
            int param;
            switch (argv[0][1]) {
                case 'a':
                    printf("case a\n"); 
                    argv++;
                    if (argv[0][0]) {
                        param = atoi(argv[0]);
                        test1(param);
                    } else {
                        printf("Missing argument");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    printf("case b\n"); 
                    argv++;
                    if (argv[0][0]) {
                        param = atoi(argv[0]);
                        test2(param);
                    } else {
                        printf("Missing argument");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    printf("case c\n"); 
                    argv++;
                    if (argv[0][0]) {
                        param = atoi(argv[0]);
                        test3(param);
                    } else {
                        printf("Missing argument");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```